# Did Mordechai have children?

Tags: purim, children-parenting, megillat-esther, historical-figures

Megillas Esther ends by saying:  וְדֹבֵר שָׁלוֹם לְכָל־זַרְעוֹ - and speaking peace to all his seed.
I realize Rashi applies this to the previous clause, of all the nation, but perhaps there are interpretations that are not in accordance with this.

Did Mordechai have children? With whom? What information, if any, is available about them?

Comment: You're asking about _Mordochay_'s children **only** according to views that the final _pasuk_ of _Ester_ is referring to such children?

Comment: @msh210, yes, if any such views exist

Comment: So -- just to be clear -- if _Rashi_ talks about _Mordochay_'s children somewhere, you don't want to know about it. Right?

Comment: @msh210 +1 on your top comment just because I enjoyed seeing "*Mordochay*."

Comment: @msh210 Rashi's different explanations are not necessarily interdependent.

Comment: @Fred Odd, because msh210 claims [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5840/mordchi/5853#comment6870_5853) (now deleted) that he does not read מרדכי with a kamatz under the dalet.

Comment: @msh210 sorry, I misunderstood, if Rashi elsewhere (not on Esther 10:3) implies that Mordechai had children I would **definitely** like to know about it

Answer (score 9):

Megilla 13b says that Ester would "rise from the bosom of Achashverosh and immerse herself and sit in the bosom of Mordechai". [Tosfos Harosh](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40708&st=&pgnum=17) asks how this was permitted due to the law of "havchana" (the requirement for a women to abstain from relations for three months between husbands to identify the father), and explains that she utilized anti-contraceptive techniques to avert the problem. He then asks if so, how was Koresh born, and (according to one answer) explains that Koresh was in fact Mordechai's biological son, and was only referred to as Achashverosh'es son because he grew up in his house.

Comment: Nice, but it would still be good to have a direct source for לְכָל; it can't mean all of his one child.

Comment: @michoel see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13095/was-darius-jewish By the way, I think it's daryavesh and not koresh

Comment: @response I was just quoting Tosfos Harosh who says Koresh. But see Rosh Hashana 3b that Koresh and Daryavesh are the same person.

Answer (score 4):

Chazal say (and the medrash brings this pasuk as a proof) that a person's students can be considered like his children. Thus  וְדֹבֵר שָׁלוֹם לְכָל־זַרְעוֹ is referring to his students who are viewed as his children.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to discount Rashi you can simply say that זַרְעוֹ refers to Mordechai's descendants through Esther (whom the Megillah calls his daughter). She had a son, Daryavesh who would be Mordechai's grandson.

Comment: Esther was Mordechai's daughter??

Comment: @DoubleAA that is what the words say וּבְמוֹת אָבִיהָ וְאִמָּהּ, לְקָחָהּ מָרְדֳּכַי לוֹ לְבַת

Comment: So she's his adopted daughter...