The Mordechai or the Mordechee?
I have heard the sefer, which is officially known as פסקי רב מרדכי (found in most gemaras directly after the Ri"f), referred to as both "The Mordechai" (where the final syllable rhymes with "hi"), and "The Mordechee" (where the final syllable rhymes with "he").
Ignoring the fact that "the" doesn't make much sense (seeing as it's just a name, it doesn't need a definite article), is there any reason why it would be pronounced "ee" and not "ai" at the end, like the name in Tanach? If not, where did that pronunciation come from?

Dupe? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5840/32959

@Qwertrl Yup! Thought I had seen the question on here, but I couldn't find it

(You refer to the Rif as "the Rif", but you're bothered by "the Mordechai"?)

@shmosel I don't get the comparison. Rif is an abbreviation of his name: Rabbi Yitzchak (or Isaac) of Fez. Mordechee is seemingly just a mispronunciation

I'm referring to your objection to "the"

@shmosel oh. That's the reason I'm ignoring that little problem. Although there, I assume it comes from the Hebrew, where saying הרב יצחק makes sense. (Even in English, saying "the" before a title makes more sense than before a name, like how people will sometimes say "the reverend x")

I assume it's shorthand for "the [commentary known as] Mordechai".

May not be the most accurate but, I heard may times Rav Yitzchak Yosef pronounced it as Mordechi
